# Property is missing in Interface when passed to parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an issue with a property missing in my App Component from my interface in my child component.

Tours Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export interface ITourProps {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    info: string;
    image: string;
    price: string;
}

export const Tours = ({ id, name, info, image, price }: ITourProps) => {
    const [readMore, setReadMore] = useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
        <section className="border-2" key={id}>
            <article>
                <img src={image} alt={name} />
                <p>{name}</p>
                <p>{price}</p>
                <p>
                    {readMore ? info : `${info.substring(0, 200)}...`}
                    <button onClick={() => setReadMore(!readMore)}>{readMore ? 'show less' : 'read more'}</button>
                </p>
            </article>
            <button>remove plz</button>
        </section>
    );
};
```

When I pass the component into the parent, it complains that `Property 'id' is missing in type '{ key: string; image: string; price: string; info: string; name: string; }' but required in type 'ITourProps'.`  In the API, one of the properties is "id", is this error saying that "id" doesn't exist?  Is there an issue with how I'm the key or is there a better option?

Here is the App Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Tours, ITourProps } from './components/Tours';
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://course-api.com/react-tours-project';

function App() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [tours, setTours] = useState<ITourProps[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchTours = async () => {
            const results = await axios(url);
            setTours(results.data);
            setLoading(false);
        };
        fetchTours();
    }, []);

    return (
            <main>
                <div>
                    <h2>Our Tours</h2>
                </div>
                {tours.map((tour) => (
                    <Tours key={tour.id} image={tour.image} price={tour.price} info={tour.info} name={tour.name} />
                ))}
            </main>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the `IToursProp` interface as required to have an `id` property. However, when you render the `Tours` component, you *don't* provide an `id`.

```
<Tours key={tour.id} image={tour.image} price={tour.price} info={tour.info} name={tour.name} />
```

You will need to either provide an `id` to `Tours` or not make it required.